# Why does my D5100 rear display turn off automatically after about 10 seconds?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100, camera-settings, rear-lcd

When I use the screen as a viewfinder, it works fine. But when I use it to show the settings, it turns off after around 10 sec. I've to press the info button to turn it back on.

Is there some setting that can cause this or my camera is faulty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for **c2: Auto off Timers** in the *Custom Settings Menu*. This is explained on page 160 of the [Nikon D5100 Reference Manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5100RM_EN.pdf) — not to be confused with the abridged [User's Manual](http://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5100_EN.pdf), which leaves out most of the details.

It sounds like you are looking to change **Auto meter-off**, which Nikon describes as the time the "information display remain[s] on when no operations are performed". When set to `normal`, that goes off after 8 seconds. Changing it to `long` will give you a minute.

Comment: That worked, Thanks. One more thing, what's the proper name for the eye viewfinder (when you need to hook the camera to your eye)?

Comment: "The viewfinder"?

Comment: The followup is addressed at [What's the proper name for the eye viewfinder?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/50028/1943)