# What's the proper name for the eye viewfinder?

Tags: terminology, viewfinder

I can use the screen as a viewfinder or the smaller, eye viewfinder on most cameras. Is there a proper name for the eye viewfinder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply called the **viewfinder**. It can be optical (on an SLR) or electronic (on a mirrorless camera, basically it's a second, smaller screen). Don't say viewfinder when talking about the back display/screen, that will only confuse people - the terminology for using the display to compose your shots is [live preview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_preview).

Answer (score 1):

Typically **viewfinder** means the one you bring to your eye, and the screen on the back is more commonly referred to as the screen or LCD. :)

If you want to be more specific, you can call it an **eye-level viewfinder** to make it distinct from using a flip-up LCD as a **waist-level viewfinder**, like the ground glass screens on TLRs.